# What storage type do I use now since websql is deprecated?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, local-storage, indexeddb, web-sql

[WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) is deprecated now and IndexedDB wasn't implemented to cordova yet. So, what storage type you are using, guys?

I think to use a Native SQLite Android Plugin, but I don't know if is the only and best way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to keep using WebSQL for the moment.
you should build a separated js wrapper to your db, so it will be easy to replace when time comes.

but for the moment- it works and supported by the mobile browsers, and threfore you have nothing to worry about.

you can read this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/persistencejs/KYSWQ1H8hL0

also, keep in mind that if you intend to use plugin for native storage, you will not be able to use Phonegap Build, so you may want to consider it.